# AWS Jenkins No space left on device

Tags: amazon-web-services, jenkins, amazon-ec2

Today my Jenkins start failing and blocking access due to this following error:

```
java.io.IOException: No space left on device
    at sun.nio.ch.FileDispatcherImpl.write0(Native Method)
    at sun.nio.ch.FileDispatcherImpl.write(FileDispatcherImpl.java:60)
    at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.writeFromNativeBuffer(IOUtil.java:93)
    at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.write(IOUtil.java:65)
    at sun.nio.ch.FileChannelImpl.write(FileChannelImpl.java:211)
    at hudson.util.FileChannelWriter.write(FileChannelWriter.java:73)
    at java.io.Writer.write(Writer.java:192)
    at hudson.util.AtomicFileWriter.write(AtomicFileWriter.java:163)
    at java.io.Writer.write(Writer.java:157)
    at hudson.XmlFile.write(XmlFile.java:191)
    at jenkins.model.Jenkins.save(Jenkins.java:3474)
    at jenkins.model.Jenkins.<init>(Jenkins.java:1012)
    at hudson.model.Hudson.<init>(Hudson.java:86)
    at hudson.model.Hudson.<init>(Hudson.java:82)
    at hudson.WebAppMain$3.run(WebAppMain.java:298)
Caused: hudson.util.HudsonFailedToLoad
    at hudson.WebAppMain$3.run(WebAppMain.java:315)
```

In fact my Jenkins storage is full. According to aws documentation, I increased the Storage size from the portal to 24Gb. After that I accesses my ec2 instance from the terminal.

Following those steps:
https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/ebs-volume-size-increase/

I was able to increase the storage volume as follow

```
NAME    MAJ:MIN RM  SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
loop0     7:0    0 33.3M  1 loop /snap/amazon-ssm-agent/3552
loop1     7:1    0 55.5M  1 loop /snap/core18/1997
loop2     7:2    0 32.3M  1 loop /snap/snapd/13170
loop3     7:3    0 61.9M  1 loop /snap/core20/1169
loop4     7:4    0 32.3M  1 loop /snap/snapd/12883
loop5     7:5    0 55.4M  1 loop /snap/core18/2128
loop6     7:6    0   25M  1 loop /snap/amazon-ssm-agent/4046
loop7     7:7    0 70.3M  1 loop /snap/lxd/21029
loop8     7:8    0 61.8M  1 loop /snap/core20/1081
loop9     7:9    0 67.3M  1 loop /snap/lxd/21545
xvda    202:0    0   24G  0 disk 
└─xvda1 202:1    0   24G  0 part /
```

The `xvda` has been upgraded to 24G, with is perfect, I was able to start Jenkins service. But when I tried to login I got once more the same error above.
To double check that everything is correct, I run the command `df -hT`, and the result was this

```
Filesystem     Type      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/root      ext4      7.7G  7.7G     0 100% /
devtmpfs       devtmpfs  2.0G     0  2.0G   0% /dev
tmpfs          tmpfs     2.0G     0  2.0G   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs          tmpfs     394M   41M  354M  11% /run
tmpfs          tmpfs     5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
tmpfs          tmpfs     2.0G     0  2.0G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/loop0     squashfs   34M   34M     0 100% /snap/amazon-ssm-agent/3552
/dev/loop1     squashfs   56M   56M     0 100% /snap/core18/1997
/dev/loop4     squashfs   33M   33M     0 100% /snap/snapd/12883
/dev/loop5     squashfs   56M   56M     0 100% /snap/core18/2128
/dev/loop6     squashfs   25M   25M     0 100% /snap/amazon-ssm-agent/4046
/dev/loop7     squashfs   71M   71M     0 100% /snap/lxd/21029
/dev/loop8     squashfs   62M   62M     0 100% /snap/core20/1081
/dev/loop9     squashfs   68M   68M     0 100% /snap/lxd/21545
/dev/loop2     squashfs   33M   33M     0 100% /snap/snapd/13170
/dev/loop3     squashfs   62M   62M     0 100% /snap/core20/1169
tmpfs          tmpfs     394M     0  394M   0% /run/user/1000
tmpfs          tmpfs      10M  3.2M  6.9M  32% /tmp
tmpfs          tmpfs     394M     0  394M   0% /run/user/113
```

I see that `/dev/root` is 100% used. But I cannot upgrade the Size of that and I couldn't find any documentation on how to upgrade the volume. If I try to run the command:

```
sudo growpart /dev/root 1
```

I get this error:

```
WARN: unknown label 
failed [sfd_dump:1] sfdisk --unit=S --dump /dev/root
sfdisk: /dev/root: does not contain a recognized partition table
FAILED: failed to dump sfdisk info for /dev/root
```

Sorry I am a total newbie here and this is the first time I am facing this issue.

Can please anyone explain me how I can solve this error

Thank you so much for your time and help

Comment: Jenkins is usually installed in /var/lib/jenkins, which appears to be in the root volume. The big directories are the (app) log directory and then the logs for each build, in jobs/folder/jobs/jobname/builds. If you have no log rotation, it grows. You can safely delete the app log and install logrotate (search Jenkins logrotate) . Then start Jenkins and set a job log retention policy. You could run "find /var/lib/Jenkins/jobs -type d -prune -exec do -hs {} \;" to see how big those are b4 and after. You will have to probably force a job log cleanup (groovy script somewhere on S/O).

Comment: Also, if you archiveArtifacts, they stay in the builds dirs too. Cleanup workspace after build (cleansWS) will also save space. Consider setting up a separate volume for Jenkins and move installation to there. And make sure you have no core dumps lying around!

Answer (score 0):

Even though you added some storage and enlarged xvda1 partition you didn't enlarge main filesystem (root volume group). I would be good to see output of **lsblk, vgs, pvs** commands as well as general info about your OS. It is quite likely you need to add available space (from xvda1 partition) to the root vg (/dev/root has still only 7.7G).

PS. to be honest I don't know the command `<growpart>` but instead of `growpart /dev/root` I would use `growpart /dev/xvda 1` - to be aligned with the instruction (`/dev/xvda` is the name of the disk attached)

Answer (score 0):

After growing the partition, you need to resize the filesystem too:

```
resize2fs /dev/xvda1
```